# C#: Parse IIS log-files efficient, create statistics

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, iis, logging

what is the best way to parse an IIS 7 log file? Are there free c# classes I can use or is there a little example project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [LogParser](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ParsingMyIISLogFilesWithLogParser22ToLearnMoreAboutBlogsStatsFromNewsGatorAndNewsGatorOnline.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

I agree with [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473914/c-parse-iis-log-files-efficient-create-statistics/4473937#4473937), LogParser is your top bet. Most, if not all of its functionality is exposed via a COM API which you could import into your project via COM interop:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For good open source alternatives, check out [awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/). Analog is another good option.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there free c# classes I can use or is there a little example project?

I wrote a little parser class in C# (.NET Core). See source here https://github.com/alexnolasco/32120528/

Example,

```
// List requests by hour
var q = new W3CReader(textReader).Read()
             .GroupBy(r => r.UtcTime().RoundUp(TimeSpan.FromHours(1)))
             .Select(g => new
             {
                    Hour = g.Key,
                    Count = g.Count()
             });
foreach (var r in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", r.Hour, r.Count);
}
```